# Error with Deprecated

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, content-management-system

Hi im getting this error

**Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /home/hj016/public_html/SSTW/index.php on line 10**

below is the code

```
// Determine which page ID to use in our query below ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (!isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $pageid = '1';
} else {
    $pageid = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['pid']); // filter everything but numbers for security
}
```

Comment: Have you googled on your error msg?

Answer (score 0):

use the preg_replace instead: http://www.php.net/preg_replace

ereg_* functions should not be used anymore.

Use this:

```
$string = preg_replace ( '|\D|', '', $string );
```